# Unremitting salutation

Tags: letter-writing, salutations, valediction

Even though I am all in favor of salutations and complimentary closes, when exchanging more than a couple of mails with the same person, I feel that starting yet another reply with `Dear Mr. Smith` gets somewhat worn and moreover stiff, even awkward if you like.

Hence, I was wondering whether it would be considered ill-mannered to drop the salutation after the first (second, third?) mail and jump to addressing the actual subject matter *directly*.

Correspondingly, if I drop the salutation, should/can I omit the valediction as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often leave off the "Dear" in such circumstances:

> Mr Smith:
>   In regards to our previous conversation...

Moreover, if Mr. Smith has signed one of his emails to me in a manner such as this:

> Best regards,
>
> Jeff
>
> Jeff Smith
>   President, EL&U Inc.

Then I might take that as a cue, and I may take the liberty of beginning subsequent emails thusly:

> Jeff,
>   Thanks for getting back to me...

Comment: What about signing the letter/mail? Do you take the liberty and skip the `Best regards, Yours truly, etc..` as well or is that rather something that _always_ should conclude a letter?

Comment: It depends on the level of familiarity, how long the correspondence is running back-and-forth, and any difference in levels of position.  If I'm writing a high-ranking executive, I'm more inclined to leave it in.  As the correspondence lengthens, I might shorten the closure, or make it less formal (e.g., `Regards,` in lieu of `Best Regards,`).  Sometimes I'll simply use `Thanks,` or `Thanks again,` – those short and concise, yet retain some measure of politeness.

Answer (score 2):

In real paper-in-envelope correspondence I'd keep to the formal letter structure.

But in email, which is less formal, and between quick exchanges in a continuing dialogue I will typically go to just the person's name and a comma as an opening and sometimes if the conversation contiues long enough I drop even that and just start typing.
Similarly, you can reduce the closing to simply your a dash and your name or no close at all if the conversation is well established and all pretense of formality has worn off.

It really depends on the level of formality you believe the situation requires.