# Salutation for job application

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing, salutations

I don't the know the exact receiver for the job.I don't even know the company's name because i found the job position online.I only know the email.How should i start the letter?
I read that for that kind of salutation, the proper way to start is with "Dear Mr.Lastname", but i don't know the name.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. I'm afraid writing advice is specifically off-topic; see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic).

Comment: what about this?http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62851/unremitting-salutation

Comment: or this?http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107172/greetings-in-the-beginning-of-an-email

Comment: The traditional salutation in this case is **Dear Sir or Madam:** Note that what you are writing is a job _application_, not _apply_.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Thanks!Accepted answer.I don't know i can accept it because question is off topic according to http://english.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic

Comment: @Dchris: Can't accept a comment anyway. You can pay me later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greedily promoting from comment: The traditional salutation in this case is
**Dear Sir or Madam:**

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add that, if you know the actual job title of the person, you can also use that.  For example,

"Dear Human Resources Specialist:"

For what it's worth, About.com has a [survey](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/coverlettertips/a/how-to-address-email-cover-letter.htm) that suggests that if you don't know at all, "Dear Hiring Manager:" appears to be the most preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question may depend on the conventions in the recipient country; specifically, American, British & Cypriot conventions may vary.  I'm writing from a British perspective.

I can't recall ever coming across correspondence addressed *Dear [job title]* as proposed by @chaosamoeba. That is not to say that it is not standard practice in some regions, and the link in chaosamoeba's answer does suggest that format.

On the other hand, *Dear Sir or Madam* (as suggested by @AndrewLazarus) is quite common in the UK, but one that I was taught to avoid.

I was taught that:

1. if you are writing a letter addressed to a **company**, ***even if*** marked for the attention a particular department or position (e.g. Attn: Hiring Manager); that is to say that the letter is **not addressed to an individual person by name**, then the format should be:

   > **Dear Sirs**
   >   Re: [subject] (e.g. *Vacancy for ...*)
   >   [body of letter]
   >   **Yours faithfully** [or ***Yours truly*** as a more old-fashioned closing].
   >   [signature]
   >   ***[your name]*** (typed or written clearly, e.g. in capital letters)
2. if you are writing a letter addressed to a **named person**, then the correct format is:

   > **Dear [title] [surname]** (e.g. *Ms Jones*) (unless you know them by first name)
   >   Re: [subject]
   >   [body of letter]
   >   **Yours sincerely**
   >   [signature]
   >   ***[your name]*** (typed or written clearly, e.g. in capital letters)

So my advice to the questioner would actually be to **check the conventions used in the country you are writing to**.

Comment: I would think it would be better ***not*** to use "Dear Sirs" if there is a possibility that a woman will be reading this email. Some women may be offended by that salutation. Did whoever taught you to use "Dear Sirs" rather than "Dear Sir or Madam" give a justification for this decision?

Comment: @PeterShor  I wasn't discussing 'benefit': I was discussing (what I believe to be) standard **British** practice. If the letter is *addressed to* (i.e. in the actual address at the top of the letter - *not* in the salutation) a company or department, then that is clearly an "it" - not a male or female person. Hence, "Dear Sirs" (plural), which is clearly *not* addressing an individual person, and so the  gender of the actual reader becomes irrelevant. I was not addressing US practice - and indeed I advised the questioner to check local conventions.

Comment: @PeterShor (2) - You changed your comment while I was replying, hence my reference to 'benefit' no longer applies! As regards 'justification', it was a looong(!) time ago - well before feminism was an issue - but I think my first comment actually addresses you question.